# Merge two datasets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have previously worked with Stata and am now trying to get the same done with Python. However, I have troubles with the merge command. Somehow I must be missing something. My two dataframes I want to merge look like this:

```
 df1:
 Date id Market_Cap
 2000 1  400
 2000 2  200
 2001 1  410
 2001 2  220

 df2:
 id Ticker
 1   Shell
 2   ExxonMobil
```

My aim now is to get the following dataset:

```
Date id Market_Cap  Ticker
2000 1  400        Shell 
2000 2  200        ExxonMobil 
2001 1  410        Shell 
2001 2  220        ExxonMobil
```

I tried the following command:

```
merged= pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on="id")
```

This merges the datasets, but gives me only nan's in the Ticker column.
I looked at several sources and maybe I am mistaken, but isn't the "left" command the right thing do to for my purpose? I also tried "right" and "outer". They don't get the result I want to and "inner" does not seem to work here in general.

Am I missing something crucial?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thyere is problem your column `id` in one df is `object` (obviously `string`) and another `int`, so no match and get `NaN`.

If have same [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
print (df1['id'].dtypes)
int64
print (df2['id'].dtypes)
int64

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on="id")
print (merged)
   Date  id  Market_Cap      Ticker
0  2000   1         400       Shell
1  2000   2         200  ExxonMobil
2  2001   1         410       Shell
3  2001   2         220  ExxonMobil
```

Another solution if need add only one new column is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['Ticker'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['Ticker'])
print (df1)
   Date  id  Market_Cap      Ticker
0  2000   1         400       Shell
1  2000   2         200  ExxonMobil
2  2001   1         410       Shell
3  2001   2         220  ExxonMobil
```

Simulate your problem:

```
print (df1['id'].dtypes)
object
print (df2['id'].dtypes)
int64

df1['Ticker'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['Ticker'])
print (df1)
   Date id  Market_Cap Ticker
0  2000  1         400    NaN
1  2000  2         200    NaN
2  2001  1         410    NaN
3  2001  2         220    NaN
```

And solution is convert to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) (or column `id` in `df2` to `str`):

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'].astype(int)
#alternatively
#df2['id'] = df2['id'].astype(str)
df1['Ticker'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['Ticker'])
print (df1)
   Date  id  Market_Cap      Ticker
0  2000   1         400       Shell
1  2000   2         200  ExxonMobil
2  2001   1         410       Shell
3  2001   2         220  ExxonMobil
```