# How to merge two datasets by specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm playing around with the Kaggle dataset "European Soccer Database" and want to combine it with another FIFA18-dataset.

My problem is the name-column in these two datasets are using different format.

For example: "lionel messi" in one dataset and in the other it is "L. Messi"

I would to convert the "L. Messi" to the lowercase version "lionel messi" for all rows in dataset.

What would be the most intelligent way to go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two datasets in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909479/merge-two-datasets-in-pandas)

Comment: Its not easy to merge based on partial match

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to convert the names in both dataframes into a common format so they can be matched.*  Let's assume that in `df1` names are in the `L. Messi` format and in `df2` names are in the `lionel messi` format.  What would a common format look like?  You have several choices, but one option would be all lowercase, with just the first initial followed by a period: `l. messi`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['L. Messi'], 'x': [1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['lionel messi'], 'y': [2]})

df1.names = df1.names.str.lower()
df2.names = df2.names.apply(lambda n: n[0] + '.' + n[n.find(' '):])

df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='names', right_on='names')
```

***Note**: This approach is totally dependent on the names being "matchable" in this way.  There are plenty of cases that could cause this simple approach to fail.  If a team has two members, `Abby Wambach` and `Aaron Wambach`, they'll both look like `a. wambach`.  If one dataframe tries to differentiate them by using other initials in their name, like `m.a. wambach` and `a.k. wambach`, the naive matching will fail.  How you handle this depends on the size your data - maybe you can try match most players this way, and see who gets dropped, and write custom code for them.