# i have 2 datasets xy and xi and i want to combine them to make one data set how can i do it

Tags: python, pandas

i want to merge them to get one dataset
I have split datasets into two from ms excel and then i want to combine them again because i wanted to exclude one colum[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3gw9.png)n

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data_set = pd.read_csv("D:/pycharm projects/ML_Project_data_preprocessing/Datadriven.csv")
xi=data_set.iloc[:,0:3].values
xy=data_set.iloc[:,4:6].values

print(xi)
print(xy)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two datasets in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909479/merge-two-datasets-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat function in pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
part1 = df.iloc[:,0:3]
part2 = df.iloc[:,3:]

pd.concat([part1,part2], axis=1)
```

More reference for Join, merge and concat [check this link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is filtering out one row, it can be easier to just filter the original dataset instead of splitting it and then combining:

```
df[~(df.index == 3)]
```

If you don't have a numeric index in your dataframe, you can call `df.reset_index()` first:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[~(df.index == 3)]
df = df.set_index(original_index)
```